# SQL query: find all devices that have ALL of the Ids passed in

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have got two tables.

Devices

- DeviceId
- DeviceName

and

DeviceAttribute

- DeviceAttributeId
- Attributeid
- DeviceId

Now, I am try to write a query, in which I pass in a number of attribute Ids, and I want to find all devices that have ALL of the Ids passed in.

I am passing the Ids in as XML, and I am then able to transform this data into a temporary table, which each Id in its own row.

So, at this point, assume all the attributes I want to match are in a table -

**CREATE TABLE #TempAttribute (AttributeId int)**

So, I may want to find all devices which have attributeIds 3,34 and 67

I have got a query which concatenates all the devices attribute Ids into one column, but I'm not sure if this is going in the right direction:

```
SELECT deviceID
 , [Name]
 , (SELECT CAST(cast(attributeID as varchar(10)) + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM deviceattribute 
     WHERE (deviceID = device.deviceID) 
     order by attributeID
     FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) AS attribs
    FROM device
```

Comment: I think you are WAY overcomplicating this...

Comment: I certainly was! Was getting myself down the completely wrong path, and didn't think of the obvious solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @NumberOfAttributes INT;

INSERT INTO #TempAttribute
SELECT DISTINCT .... /* Rest of your XML query*/

SET @NumberOfAttributes= @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT DeviceId,
       DeviceName
FROM   Devices
WHERE  DeviceId IN (SELECT DeviceId
                    FROM   DeviceAttribute da
                           JOIN #TempAttribute ta
                             ON da.Attributeid = ta.Attributeid
                    GROUP  BY DeviceId
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = @NumberOfAttributes) ;
```

Comment: That is, 100%, what I was looking for!
Pretty obvious once you see how!
Thanks very much!!